# Replace text in a children node of a tbody

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML generated by SharePoint, and want to eliminate the ": Real Estate:" from the text element. I just can't figure out how. Note that the groupstring in the tbody is a good selector, as I need to do this to all the tobody with this attribute present.

```
<tbody id="titl7-1_" groupstring="%3B%23Real%20Estate%3AEasement%3B%23">  
  <tr>  
      <td class="ms-gb" nowrap="nowrap" colspan="100">  
        <a onclick="javascript:ExpCollGroup('7-1_', 'img_7-1_',event, false);return false;" href="javascript:">  
: Real Estate:Easement
        <span style="font-weight: lighter; display: inline-block;">(1)</span>  
  </td>  
  </tr>  
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Target the anchor within the tbody with that attribute, and use text() with a callback to do a string replace on the text in the anchor.

```
$('tbody[groupstring="%3B%23Real%20Estate%3AEasement%3B%23"] a').text(function(_,txt) {
    return txt.replace(': Real Estate:','');
});
```

Comment: Was typing while you were editing the answer I suppose. You'll beat me next time.